# css: adding a background-image-url on an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I'm trying to add social icons on the footer of a webpage via one single sprite image.

I can't get the `<a>` tag to have a `background-image: url`. Seems to work fine for other elements like `<li>` though.

```css
#no-work a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  Background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}

#works li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  Background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}
```

```html
// This doesn't work
<ul id="no-work">
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>

// But why does this work???
<ul id="works">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor tags are inline elements. That means their width and height are defined by their contents. You have blank anchor tags.

The simplest solution is to style the `a` tags with `display: inline-block`. This allows your `width` and `height` values to work. See the edits to your code:

```css
#works-now a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  Background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}

#works li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  Background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}
```

```html
// This works now
<ul id="works-now">
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>

// But why does this work???
<ul id="works">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah okay this makes so much more sense now. Is `display: inline` the default for any element not specified here? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Answer (score 3):

It will work, but you need to put a `display:block` on your `<a>` tag.

```
#no-work a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}
```

```css
#no-work a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}

#works li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/0ff");
}
```

```html
<ul id="no-work">
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
</ul>

// But why does this work???
<ul id="works">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works because the `li` has the `display: block` attribute by default.

The anchor tag doesn't

If you apply `display: block`to the a it will show too

Comment: what's the default `display` value of a? I don't see it on the css-default list values. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp . Also, putting `display:block` worked

Comment: It doesn't have a default `display` value. It is usually wrapped in a `<p></p>` or `h(x)` tag though, which has `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify height and width to the `<li>` then make your anchor tag `display: block` so that the anchor takes up the size of the parent `<li>`.

Something like

```
#works li {
    display: inline-block; //if you are aligning on the same line
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#works li a {
    display: block;
    Background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/0ff");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#works a.social-icon-specific-1 {
    background-position: 100px 100px; //position your sprite accordingly
}
#works a.social-icon-specific-2 {
    background-position: 200px 200px;
}
```

Assuming that you are using a sprite, you just move the background position accordingly.